# How to make a v-for with two data source in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

I can't make this to work unlike the old vuejs do where I can insert two computed components in one v-for.

I created a Search Input and Sort Buttons:

```js
    computed: {
      filteredItems() {
        return this.items.filter((item) => {
          return item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.searchOne.toLowerCase())
        })
      },
      filteredBtn() {
        if (this.filterer === '') return this.items
        else return this.items.filter(f => f.category === this.filterer)
      },
    }
```

```html
<v-container fluid>
      <!-- title and search zone -->
      <v-layout>
        <h1>eBooks</h1>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer> 
        <v-text-field v-model="searchOne" label="Search" placeholder="Search a Title in Journal/Articles..." append-outer-icon="mdi-magnify" outlined />
      </v-layout>
      <!-- title and search zone -->
      <!-- sortbtn zone -->
      <div class="mx-5">
           <v-btn small text color="grey" v-for="(f,i) in filterBtn" :key="i" @click="onClick(f.name)">
            <v-icon left small>{{ f.icon }}</v-icon>
            <span class="caption text-lowercase">{{ f.name }}</span>
           </v-btn>
           <v-btn small text color="grey" class="ml-10">
            <v-icon left small>mdi-archive-refresh</v-icon>
            <span class="caption text-lowercase" @click="reset">Reset</span>
           </v-btn>
      </div>
      <!-- sortbtn zone -->
      <!-- main content -->
      <v-row wrap>
        <v-col xs12 md6 v-for="(item, i) in filteredBtn || filteredItems" :key="i" class="mx-5">
          <v-card class="mx-auto my-12" max-width="340" elevation="10">
            <v-img height="250" :src="item.src"></v-img>
            <v-card-title class="text-wrap">{{ item.title }}</v-card-title>
            <v-card-text>
              <span>{{ item.sub }}</span>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-actions>
              <v-chip small>{{ item.category }}</v-chip>
              <v-spacer />
              <v-btn outlined rounded :href="item.link" target="_blank" color="#005FFF">Start Reading</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
          </v-card>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <!-- main content -->
    </v-container>
```

I've used this kind of method in the older version of vuejs, but after the update, this won't allow to work:

```
v-for="(item, i) in filteredBtn || filteredItems"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution:

```js
computed: {
      filteredBtn() {
        if (this.filterer === '') return this.items
        else return this.items.filter(f => f.category === this.filterer)
      },
      filteredItems() {
        if (this.searchOne) {
          return this.items.filter((item) => {
            return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(this.searchOne.toLowerCase())
        })
        } else {
          return this.filteredBtn
        }
      },
    },
```

```html
<v-col xs12 md6 v-for="(item, i) in filteredItems" :key="i" class="mx-5">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to combine using a single computed property.

```
v-for="(item, i) in computedItems"
```

```js
computedItems() {
  return this.items.filter((item) => {

    if (this.filterer !== '' && !(this.items.filter(f => f.category === this.filterer) return false

    return item.title.toLowerCase().match(this.searchOne.toLowerCase())
   }) 
}
```

Comment: thank you I didn't realize the other options but I tried it too with the parenthesis it didn't bring any errors but only one works on computed property.

Comment: Great! I will update the solution then, to help others that go down the same rabbit hole.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English but what I mean is it works but only one computed property is functioning. For ex. the filtered button works perfectly but when you try the search input it doesn't work and when you reverse it the search input works properly but the filtered button doesn't.

Comment: got it. try updated solution.

Comment: I've tested it, sir, but unfortunately still has the same result.

Comment: Your logic is missing the case where the `searchOne` is empty

Comment: Sir thank you so much for these awesome tips and for helping me figure this out.